# Get some elements by jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have some html elements, like that:

```html
<ul>
<li>1</li>    <!-- Needed -->
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>    <!-- Needed -->
<li class="choosed">5</li>
<li class="choosed">6</li>
<li>7</li>    <!-- Needed -->
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>    <!-- Needed -->
<li class="choosed">11</li>
<li class="choosed">12</li>
<li class="choosed">13</li>
<li>14</li>    <!-- Needed -->
<li>15</li>
<li>16</li>
<li>17</li>
<li>18</li>    <!-- Needed -->
</ul>
```

How to get these items. Result should be like that:

```js
[
{start:1,end:4},
{start:7,end:10},
{start:14,end:18},
]
```

So i need get only first and last elements between elements with class

Comment: This is not really a jQuery or HTML problem; getting all <li> elements with jQuery (or without it) is trivial, and how to turn that into ranges based on whether they were chosen or not is a matter of iterating over them with a suitable algorithm. Have you tried anything yourself so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `map()` and `nextUntil()`

```js
const res = $('li:not(".choosed"):first-child, li.choosed + li:not(".choosed")').map(function() {
  let start = +$(this).text()
  let end = +$(this).nextUntil('.choosed').last().text()
  return { start, end }
}).get()

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <!-- Needed -->
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <!-- Needed -->
  <li class="choosed">5</li>
  <li class="choosed">6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <!-- Needed -->
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <!-- Needed -->
  <li class="choosed">11</li>
  <li class="choosed">12</li>
  <li class="choosed">13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <!-- Needed -->
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li>18</li>
  <!-- Needed -->
</ul>
```